# Can I consign my pepper spray from Canada to China?

Tags: air-travel, legal, canada, china

I have a flight from Canada to China (by aircanada). It seems that I can't bring pepper spray to the plane, but can I consign it? Is that illegal?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  There is a related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/is-it-possible-to-carry-pepper-spray-for-self-defense .  But can you clarify what you mean by "consign"?

Comment: I think he means to post it...

Comment: I would severely doubt that there is any need for pepper spray in China. No matter where you go.

Comment: Your first question should be whether it's legal there.  A quick Google strongly suggests it isn't.

Comment: Pepper spray is not legal in China, they will confiscate it and destroy it

Answer (score 2):

Given pepper spray is considered illegal by the Chinese government, you may well be able to consign it, but it would be confiscated at destination and you may run into problems with being accused of  trying to import illegal items.

[Example in Hong Kong](http://www.defend-net.com/raysun/index.story.en.html) (I realise that's not mainland China but a quick search reveals many indicators that it's illegal through mainland China as well)

Answer (score 1):

[Discover HK](http://www.discoverhongkong.com/in/plan-your-trip/traveller-info/immigration-and-customs/customs.jsp) alleges under the heading "Points to note:"

> - While legal in some countries, various personal protection devices, such as 'mace' spray and stun gun, are prohibited in Hong Kong.

That website is overseen by the [Hong Kong Tourism Board](http://www.discoverhongkong.com/in/about-hktb/index.jsp)

> The Hong Kong Tourism Board (HKTB) is a government-subvented body tasked to market and promote Hong Kong as a travel destination worldwide and to enhance visitors' experience once they arrive.